# Array of user ids to list of user names

Tags: post-meta, array, user-meta

I'm outputting an array of user ids from metadata like so:
    `$awaygoalby = unserialize($post_meta_data['report_away-scorers'][0]);`
and I want to change each user id to the user name. So I was hoping to do something like this:

```
foreach($awaygoalby as $string){
$name = get_userdata( $string );
echo $name;
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error saying that the "Object of class WP_User could not be converted to string." What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_userdata()` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata - returns an object. You need to provide the correct return value:

```
echo $name->nicename;
```

Comment: Is that all? Thank you so much. I tried everything and just couldn't get it.